# How do I change the color scheme of my iPhone GUI?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, monodevelop

I want to customize my GUI for the iPhone in monodevelop but I can't seem to find resources that will show me how to do it.  How can I change the background color (load a picture/logo) and change the navigation bar color etc.?  Thanks in advance!  (What is the programatic way to do this?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the navigation bar color using the following code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] \
initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
[[navigationController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You can set the background color (I guess that you want to set the background color of UIView)
like this

```
UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Hope it helps! ;)